# vb.net Emoticon in richtextbox transparancy

Tags: vb.net

I've managed to change text into emoticons in a richtextbox but i'm having e problem.

When i change text into emoticons with following code, then it doesn't show the transparancy of the gif files:

```
If LCase(MainWindow.RichTextBoxChatRoom.Text).IndexOf(":d") <> -1 Then
                MainWindow.RichTextBoxChatRoom.Select(LCase(MainWindow.RichTextBoxChatRoom.Text).IndexOf(":d"), 2)
                Clipboard.SetImage(My.Resources.teeth_smile)
                MainWindow.RichTextBoxChatRoom.ReadOnly = False
                MainWindow.RichTextBoxChatRoom.Paste()
                MainWindow.RichTextBoxChatRoom.ReadOnly = True
                Empty = Empty + 1
            End If
```

the weird thing is when i copy the exact same icon out of a word document and i paste is manualy into the richtextbox. it perfectly works. see picture below:

[Screenshot RichTextBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qtjO.png)

Can someone explain why this is hapening and maybe a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `RichTextBox` does **not** have an image as background (just some color) then:

```
Using bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(My.Resources.teeth_smile.Width, My.Resources.teeth_smile.Height) 'use a bitmap with the same size of your image
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        g.Clear(MainWindow.RichTextBoxChatRoom.BackColor) 'set the color of the bitmap the same as RichTextBox

        g.DrawImage(My.Resources.teeth_smile, 0, 0, My.Resources.teeth_smile.Width, My.Resources.teeth_smile.Height) 'draw your image to bmp

        Clipboard.SetImage(bmp) 'use the bmp bitmap to paste in RichTextBox

        MainWindow.RichTextBoxChatRoom.Paste()
    End Using
End Using
```